# Convert a binary string of 0s and 1s to a bitstring in elixir

Tags: binary, elixir, bitstring

Given a string such as `"0110"`, how do I convert this to a bitstring containing the binary values represented by the string?

I checked the [`Base`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Base.html) module, but it's based on [RFC 4648](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4648) and is not designed for handling Base 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```elixir
defmodule Convert do
  def to_bitstring(str) when is_binary(str) do
    for <<byte::binary-1 <- str>>, into: <<>> do
      case byte do
        "0" -> <<0::1>>
        "1" -> <<1::1>>
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```elixir
iex> Convert.to_bitstring("0110")
<<6::size(4)>>
```

The benefit of doing it exhaustively using `case` and matching on binaries is two-fold:

1. The function will reject invalid characters
2. The error message in the above case is easy to understand:

```elixir
iex> Convert.to_bitstring("0140")
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: "4"
```

---

If you just want a quick hack, this works, but it will also happily convert nonsense like `"0140"` too, so I think the first solution is better.

```elixir
for <<byte <- str>>, into: <<>>, do: <<(byte - ?0)::1>>
```

Comment: `for <<byte <- str>>, (byte in [?0, ?1] || raise "boom"), …`

Comment: Or keep the `case` but match on `?0` and `?1`

Comment: @sabiwara sure but then you lose the point 2) above and get errors like `** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: 52`

Comment: Oh you're right. I missed that, nice!